# How to fix incorrect fields showing in ProjectID Field Selector type-ahead dropdown

Tags: acumatica

I have an instance of Acumatica 5.3 with all customizations unpublished. On the Project and Accounting forms where a ProjectID selector exists, the type-ahead drop-downs are showing 'Key - Key', instead of 'Key - Description'. The regular popup form for the selectors is working correctly. Where might an over-ride of the type-ahead drop-downs be found when all customization projects have been unpublished?

Comment: I doubt this is related to your problem but you can manually extend Acumatica by putting files in the 'App_RuntimeCode' and 'CstPublished' folders of your Acumatica website.

Comment: At the bottom right of the login screen you will see a list of the customization projects applied to the Acumatica website instance.